# SQL Server Backup failing Error :3041

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup, maintenance

I am running SQL Server 2008R2 Express edition. For all databases full backup, I am using `expressmaint.exe`. In this, I am using the command

```
-S server name -D ALL -T DB -R 
D:\SQL_BACKUP\SQL_EXPRESSMAINT_LOGS\FULL_BACKUP_LOGS -RU DAYS -RV 5 -B 
D:\SQL_BACKUP\SQL_FULL_BACKUP -BU DAYS -BV 5.
```

I have created schedule backup from Task Scheduler. It was running 3 days then after start failing the backup plan for only 1 database.
System database has been successfully running except 1 database.

> Error: BACKUP failed to complete the command BACKUP DATABASE (database name)

From logs I got this error message:

> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
>       Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

From Event Viewer logs I got below error code: 3041

> The backup or restore was aborted.BACKUP failed to complete the command BACKUP DATABASE Database Name. Check the backup application log for detailed messages.

Can you please anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

Try to increase the timeout period by adding `-TO <time period in minutes>` to your command:

```
-S server name -D ALL -T DB -R 
D:\SQL_BACKUP\SQL_EXPRESSMAINT_LOGS\FULL_BACKUP_LOGS -RU DAYS -RV 5 -B 
D:\SQL_BACKUP\SQL_FULL_BACKUP -BU DAYS -BV 5 -TO 25
```

[ExpressMaint](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=expressmaint) issues tab

Comment: Now it is working fine. Thanks for your support.